# Compare the Two hashMaps and update the HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

```
class Student_Details{
String name;
int rollNumber;
String address;
// setter and getter of above data members
}

HashMap<String,Collection<Student_Details>> oldData;
HashMap<String,Collection<Student_Details>> newData;
```

lets say the value in HashMAp oldData is:

```
abc:[{sam,12,newyork},{mike,15,gotham}]
xyz:[{riphunter,32,new york}]
```

Hashmap newData contains:

```
abc:[{sam,12,newyork},{mike,17,London},{john,36,boston]
uvw:[{rip,39,boston}]
```

Things to do:
1)if key of newData is not present in oldData then add the key value to the oldData
2)if key of newData present in oldData then update the content of the Collection  where name should not change .for example the final map(oldData)for above example should have following contents

```
abc:[{sam,12,newyork},{mike,17,London},{john,36,boston}] 
xyz:[{riphunter,32,new york}]
uvw:[{rip,39,boston}]
```

Please help me with the solution...Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @gonzo for(String key:newData.keySet()){
if oldData containsKey(Key )}

Comment: @gonzo for(String key:newData.keySet()){
                if oldData containsKey(Key ){
                Collection<Student_details> oldDetail=oldData.get(key)
                 Collection<Student_details> newDetail=newData.get(key)
// with this new collection I am able to get the Student name 
// now on the basis of Student name I have to update the Collection ollDeatils 
}
                    
}
else{
oldData.put(key,newData.get(key)
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `putAll()` to achieve

> Copies all of the mappings from the specified map to this map. These mappings will replace any mappings that this map had for any of the keys currently in the specified map.

I wrote an example here, I use `map1` and `map2` to simulate your `oldData` and `newData`.

`putAll()` is a wrap for `put` method which loops `put` action. Here's the explanation of `put()`

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

Therefore, if key exist, it will update value, otherwise it stores the new key and new value

```
    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();

    map1.put("a", "1");
    map1.put("b", "2");
    map1.put("c", "3");

    map2.put("a", "10");
    map2.put("d", "4");

    Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<>();

    temp.putAll(map1);
    temp.putAll(map2);

    temp.forEach((k,v) -> System.out.println("Key:" + k + ", Value:" +v));
```

The output is:

```
Key:a, Value:10
Key:b, Value:2
Key:c, Value:3
Key:d, Value:4
```

Comment: here you are working with key as string and value as a strings but i am supposed to have a map of string and Collection<Student_Details> where i need to compare the collection of the two maps i.e oldData and newData

Comment: @adi2380 Did you try yourself?  it is the same. it doesn't matter what your value's type is.

Comment: putAll will replace the entire key/Value pair from map1 and add the key/value pair from map2 if keys are same. please have a look of the example i have mentioned above.

Answer (score -3):

First the key of the map should be the `name` of the student. Now

Then just do this for every new student

```
oldMap.put (newStudent.getName(), newStudent);
```

What it would do is to add the newStudent. If the student with this key doesn't exist then it would be added otherwise, this new value would replace the previous value since its a HashMap which doesn't support duplicate values

Comment: Key of map is `abc`, which has nothing to do with student name.

Comment: the key cannot be student name ..Suppose the key is the name of the school so data of the student i.e name roll,address should be the value .moreover only the roll no and address  should be  updated